# Checking values of Json array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json respond that I want to check and return values accordingly:
the Json code is:

```
{
 "success": "true",
 "result": "ok"
}
```

And I need to check the success status and return an array to the controller accordingly.

I was trying to decode and ask questions on the value as follow:

```
$obj = json_decode($response,true);
    if ($obj['success'] =='true')
      return array(
        'error' => 0,
        'msg' => sprintf("successfully")
      );
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong since I can't get the 0 in the error on array returns.

There is another json code that I need to deal with and it is this:

Negative Response:

```
{
“success” : “false” ,
“error”:{
        “code”:"MANDATORY_FIELDS_MISSING",
        "message”: “Phone number is a mandatory field"
    }
}
```

The same goes with this.

I would be happy if you couls assist me with gettin it to work properly.
Thank you.
Arye

Comment: Are you sure the JSON contains the string `"true"`, not the boolean `true`?

Comment: Your negative response is not valid JSON. You have to use ASCII double quotes, not curly quotes, around strings. Is that a copying error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code working fine. You are confused with printing and returning. 
Please check this:--

```
<?php 

$response = '{"success": "true","result": "ok"}';
$obj = json_decode($response,true);
    if ($obj['success'] =='true')
      print_r (array(
        'error' => 0,
        'msg' => sprintf("successfully")
      ));
?>
```

Output:-- http://prntscr.com/729h1o

So i think instead of return you need to print it out.

And you can use var_dump as well as echo `<pre/>`;print_r(your array inside if) just for look a bit good.

Comment: Solved!
Thank you all so much :)

I was there and I didn't realized that.
thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
$json = '
{
 "success": "true",
 "result": "ok"
}';

$obj = json_decode($json, true);


if ($obj['success'] == 'true')
    var_dump(array(
        'error' => 0,
        'msg' => 'successfully'
    ));
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  'error' =>
  int(0)
  'msg' =>
  string(12) "successfully"
}
```

When you run the code above, do you get the same output I see?

Comment: Solved!
Thank you all so much :)

I was there and I didn't realized that.
thank you all for helping.